How to Setup Different Maintenance windows for Node Pools Within the Same GKE
I'm managing a GKE cluster that contains multiple node pools. I need to set up different maintenance windows for these node pools to ensure that nodes in different node pools are not restarted at the same time.
I've tried looking for options in the Google Cloud Console and gcloud CLI to set maintenance windows specifically for each node pool, but I couldn't find any.
Is there a way to set up different maintenance windows for node pools within the same GKE cluster? If not, what are the best practices or workarounds to achieve this goal?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Currently there is no feature for setting up different Maintenance Windows for Node Pools within the cluster, instead you can do
You can already disable auto upgrades and manually apply updates to individual node pools (as long as you keep skew within one minor version, otherwise they will be auto upgraded).
GKE also now offers blue-green upgrades to create a new set of nodes and better control the pace/soak time.
Meanwhile you can create a feature request using Issue Tracker thread describing your issue.
